# R simulations and regression in mice()

Tags: r, simulation, regression, missing-data, r-mice

I am using the mice package in R to do multiple imputation and trying to understand the algorithm behind it.

From its documentation http://www.jstatsoft.org/v45/i03/paper, the MICE algorithm is said to be used. From my understanding, it performs MCMC using Gibbs Sampler, where simulates parameters BETA that defines the conditional distribution of Y(variable with missing value) given Y-(all other variables without Y). With the simulated BETA,the corresponding conditional distribution is defined. Then it draws values from the conditional distribution and replace missing with it. It repeats the procedure across all variables with missing values.

However, what I don't understand is that, where does the regression happen? In the mice() function, we do need to specify the 'method' parameter. For example, 'logreg' for binomial distributed variables and 'polyreg' for factor variable with more than 2 level. If imputation is done by MCMC, why would we need to specify a regression?

Some documentation indicates that MICE algorithm runs regression iteratively across all variables with missing pattern. In each time, one variable with missing is the respondent variable and all others are explanatory variables. Then fitted values are used to replace missing and move on to the next variable with missing. The next regression will include imputed data from last regression. This is the same scheme as Gibbs sampler but it seems that there is no simulation. Details are here http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/

Could anyone help me to understand what really happens in mice in R?

Comment: Because you don't have specific programming question, your question is off-topic for SO. I believe it is better suited for stats.stackexchange.com. However, I think you need to be much more specific than "help me to understand what really happens in mice" before posting there. Please study the guide lines for CV [**here**](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [**here**](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated)

Comment: It could be argued that "where does the regression happen?" is a programming question. A possible answer would be a link to the part of the code where such thing takes places, for example.

Answer (score 2):

For each variable with missing data (Y1,...,Yj,...Yk), the MICE algorithm fits a statistical model conditioning Yj on all other variables (Yj-, or a subset therof).
The type of statistical model is indicated by `method`.
This is the "regression".
The fitted model is used to draw replacements for the missing portions of Yj, given Yj-. Afterwards, the algorithm proceeds with the next variable that contains missing values.

Once all variables have been filled, the algorithm starts over.

Note that, when fitting the models, the MICE algorithm regresses the *observed* portions of Yj on the observed *and* imputed portions of Yj-.
In other words, at each iteration, the regression models condition on a different set of predictor values (hence the need for usually more than one iterations). This is slightly different from other implementations of MI.

Note also that the MICE algorithm is not formally a Gibbs sampler (see the very well-written discussion by Carpenter and Kenward, 2013).